# Swift - Run Code Stored Online

Tags: ios, swift, server, host

I know this is probably a long shot but I wanted to know if there is any relatively easy way to run swift code which is stored on a server or hosted somewhere other than the application bundle. I would like to be able to change single lines of code without having to publish an update to the app.

If anyone could help or has a work around then that would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

No it's both not possible (there is no compiler on an iOS device) and not allowed (downloading code is expressly forbidden by Apple's app store guidelines.)

So you both cannot and may not do this.

Comment: Ok. Could I change a single link in the code remotely?

Comment: Your app itself is not modifiable. You could write your app to save a link in the documents directory and invoke it from there. Then you could have your app load a new link from a server and replace the link saved in the documents directory.

Comment: @Duncan_C Ok that sounds good, Are there any posts on here about implementing that?

Comment: Not that I know of. Sometimes programming means doing original development rather than finding somebody else's code that does exactly what you want to do and pasting it into your program. Look at `NSBundle` to get the link file from your bundle. Look at using `NSFileManager` to copy it into your documents directory. Look at using `NSURLConnection` to check to see if a new file is available, and using `NSURLConnection` or `NSURLSession` to download a new file from your server if an update is available.